# Highcharts heatmap disabling color legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to create a highcharts heatmap without the color legend on the side. The suggested solution of passing

```
legend: {
 enabled: false
}
```

in the configuration only moves the legend to the bottom of the graph.

I reproduced the problem based on the example on the highcharts documentation page in this fiddle:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2z1ph5g/)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your jsFiddle has `legend: {enable: false}`. It needs to be `legend: {enabled: false}`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your jsfiddle has typo, the legend show/hide option is `enabled` not `enable`. Your question shows the correct version, updated fiddle here shows the legend hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/m2z1ph5g/1/